# Apollo Client fetchMore from useQuery does duplicate network request after every fetch

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

We have a web application. We have been extensively using Apollo + React's useQuery to give user infinite scroll experience. We recently realized that components were not loading assets after `fetchMore` was used second time. On a network tab, there was a constant loop of the first and second request.

After some debugging, I realized that I need to have a merge function in Apollo to merge data when we use `fetchMore`.

I changed code. Added AssetData in typePolicies to below:

```
export const getApolloClient = (): ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject> =>
  new ApolloClient({
    cache: new InvalidationPolicyCache({
      typePolicies: {
        AssetData: {
          keyFields: [],
          fields: {
            assets: {
              merge(existing = [], incoming: string[], { args }) {

                  return [...existing, ...incoming];
              }
            }
          }
        },
      },
      invalidationPolicies: {
        types: {
          Asset: {
            timeToLive: 29 * 60 * 1000
          }
        }
      }
    }),
    link: new HttpLink({ fetch })
  });
```

Which helped to break the loop. But I still see that after every fetchMore requests, another duplicate network call for the original query does trigger. Which actually messes up entire merge function in Apollo. I will have so much of duplicate data. So many people have reported similar issues and I tried many proposed solutions [https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/7307][1], [https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/7939][2], [https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/9668][3]

But nothing is helping me to fix it.

Here is my query:

```
 const { loading, data, error, fetchMore, networkStatus } = useQuery<
    AssetsQuery
  >(assetsQuery, {
    variables: {
      role,
      version: version,
      offset: 0,
      limit: 30,
      region
    },
    fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
    nextFetchPolicy: 'cache-first',
  });
```

In one of the thread apollo team mentioned that this issue is resolved in a new version 3.6.0. So, I also updated my apollo version from `3.2.0` to `3.6.9`, but I still have same issue.

Please let me know if you have any further suggestions

[1]: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/7307 [2]: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/7939 [3]: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/9668

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the @apollo/client package to latest version. Right now it’s `@3.7.14`. It resolved my issue.

Comment: I updated my client to `@3.7.17` and it didn't fix the issue. Turns out my issue was I had the custom merge function and had to update it for data that was on the top level. For some reason this was triggering an additional request.